# When rendering a custom form, how do I use <button> instead of <input type="submit"> for the button #type?

Tags: 8, forms

I have a render array for my custom form, which acts as a "Like" button for articles (but with custom functionality for our client). The button is defined like so:

```
...
    $form['like_btn'] = [
      '#type'   => 'button',
      '#markup' => '<img src="/path/to/like-icon.svg" width="32">',
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => ['like'],
        'id'    => ['like-btn'],
      ],
      '#ajax'   => [
        'callback' => '::updateLikesCounter',
        'disable-refocus' => FALSE,
        'event'    => 'click',
        'wrapper'  => 'like_counter',
        'progress' => [
          'type' => 'none',
        ],
      ],
    ];
...
```

However, this renders the button as `<input type="submit">` rather than a `<button>` element.

How can I make the `"button"` render element type utilize the `<button>` HTML element instead? Or, which render element `#type` should I use instead?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it already has an open issue on Drupal.org. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1671190

Comment: I did not see that issue, @Jdrupal. Thanks for the guidance.